# Why isn't the jQuery addClass method working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Environment

- Mozilla Firefox 20.0.1
- jQuery 1.7.1

I have a set of validation functions:

```
var firstName = $('#FirstName'),
    lastName = $('#LastName'),
    dateOfBirth = $('#DateOfBirth'),
    city = $('#City'),
    phone = $('#Phone'),
    email = $('#Email'),
    insType = $('#InsType'),
    otherInsType = $('#OtherInsType'),
    insID = $('#InsID'),
    service = $('#Service'),
    otherService = $('#OtherService'),
    comments = $('#Comments'),
    outOfPocket = $('#OutOfPocket'),
    permission = $('#Permission'),
    signature = $('#Signature');

function formIsValid() {
    if (missingRequiredField([
        firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, city, phone, email,
        insType, insID, service, comments, outOfPocket, permission,
        signature
    ])) {
        alert('There is a missing required field.');
        return false;
    }

    alert('The form was valid.');

    return false;
}

function missingRequiredField(objs) {
    var hasError = false;
    objs.forEach(function(o) {
        if (!$(o).val()) {
            $(o).addClass('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
    });

    return hasError;
}
```

and I know they work because when I leave the fields blank I get the `alert('There is a missing required field.');`. But for some reason the `$(o).addClass('error');` isn't actually adding the class. I know the class works because if I add it by hand the visual style looks like I want. Further, I know it's not adding the class because I check out the element in Firebug after getting the `alert`.

Am I missing something here? I thought it was this straight forward -even checked with the jQuery documentation and it looks right to me.

Here is an example of one of the fields in markup as well:

```
<div>
    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
</div>
```

## EDIT

I even pulled the `forEach` out into a basic `for` loop and the `addClass` still isn't take. The function is working because `hasError` returns `true` when a field doesn't have a value -just that stubborn `addClass`. **NOTE:** I did pull off the unnecessary `$` surrounding the `o` in this version.

```
function missingRequiredField(objs) {
    var hasError = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        var o = objs[i];
        if (!o.val()) {
            o.addClass('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
    }

    return hasError;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesnt show us what kind of object are firstName, lastName, ... are they jquery objects ?

Comment: @RafH, fair enough. I've updated the question with their declarations. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: `Array.forEach()` is not supported by IE older than IE9.

Comment: @MaratTanalin, noted -I'll change it up later to a `for`. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be o.addClass('error') as you already have $() at the top?

Comment: Make sure your elements have corresponding `id`s, not just `name`s.

Comment: @GrayB It should, but the extra `$()` also shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: That's [working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/sgGJV/), it must be something else.

Comment: Works for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/RA3GK/.

Comment: Just BTW, is the last `return false` in `formIsValid()` meant to be `return true`?

Comment: @michaelb958, yeah it would generally be returning `true`, but I've got it returning `false` at the moment to keep it from posting.

Comment: @bfavaretto, this is insane. The fiddle works, and I'm even doing all this in Firefox so there shouldn't be any real limitations, but the code on my box doesn't work. **I even pulled it out of the `forEach` into a basic `for` and that still didn't work.** What in the world is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery selectors are running before the DOM is ready, which means no elements are being selected (since they haven't been build yet).

If you select the elements after the DOM is ready, it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    firstName = $('#FirstName');
    lastName = $('#LastName');
});
```

Additionally, as other people have stated, you should convert the `.foreach()` loop into a regular `for` loop.

See the following jsbin for the example:

http://jsbin.com/uzefeg/3/edit

Comment: And that was the answer! Now that's some ***weird*** stuff my friend!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud In fact that's not weird, you just can't select elements that don't exist yet! It surprises me that nobody thought about that yesterday, myself included!

Comment: @bfavaretto, what's weird though is that the variables were in fact jQuery objects and were in fact the `input` elements on the form. Why weren't they `null` if it was *too early* (i.e. they didn't exist yet)?

Comment: When jQuery can't find an object for a selector, it returns a jQuery object with an empty list of elements. This way it doesn't crash on stuff like `$('selector').hide()` if the element doesn't exist. Early jQuery versions worked as you said, returning null or undefined, then they changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It works in the following jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nHHyQ/

Admittedly I am only using one field to test.  I know it sounds obvious, but have you styled up the error class?  Double check the spelling and the selector in your css.

**Javascript**:
    var firstName = $('#FirstName');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').click(function (e) {
            formIsValid();
        });
    });

```
function formIsValid() {
    if (missingRequiredField([
    firstName])) {
        alert('There is a missing required field.');
        return false;
    }

    alert('The form was valid.');

    return false;
}

function missingRequiredField(objs) {
    var hasError = false;
    objs.forEach(function (o) {
        if (!$(o).val()) {
            $(o).addClass('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
    });

    return hasError;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//this code should fix the problem

```
$(function(){
var firstName = $('#FirstName'),
    lastName = $('#LastName'),
    dateOfBirth = $('#DateOfBirth'),
    city = $('#City'),
    phone = $('#Phone'),
    email = $('#Email'),
    insType = $('#InsType'),
    otherInsType = $('#OtherInsType'),
    insID = $('#InsID'),
    service = $('#Service'),
    otherService = $('#OtherService'),
    comments = $('#Comments'),
    outOfPocket = $('#OutOfPocket'),
    permission = $('#Permission'),
    signature = $('#Signature');

function formIsValid() {
    if (missingRequiredField([
        firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, city, phone, email,
        insType, insID, service, comments, outOfPocket, permission,
        signature
    ])) {
        alert('There is a missing required field.');
        return false;
    }

    alert('The form was valid.');

    return false;
}

function missingRequiredField(objs) {
    var hasError = false;
    objs.forEach(function(o) {
        if (!$(o).val()) {
            $(o).addClass('error');
            hasError = true;
        }
    });

    return hasError;
}

});
```